# How to create a search block for other nodes that points to an existing search view node?

Tags: blocks, search, views

I have a node that has a view with a search form in it.  There is another view under it that displays the results.  This is our "search page."

Now, we'd like to add a block with a search field with a submit button on to our sidebar for the rest of the site.  This way you can search anytime while browsing the website's other pages.  When you search in the block and hit submit, you should be taken to the search page with the results displaying.

How do I do this?
It sounds easy enough but I can't seem to find the answer googling.